# Confusion implementing DFT circular frequency shift property in MATLAB 2015a?

Tags: matlab, dft

I am trying  to implement the DFT circular frequency shift property in MATLAB and my code is below. I have also attached a snapshot from the Proakis book where this property is highlighted but I am confused why I am not getting same equal value of LHS(Left Hand side) and RHS(Right hand  side)

```
clc;clear;close all
x=[1:8];
N=length(x)
n=0:N-1
k=0:N-1
X=fft(x)
l=3%shift amount
y=circshift(X,l,2)%here 2 means shift along 2nd dimension which are columns
W=exp(j*2*pi/N);
RHS=fft(y)
LHS=fft(W.^(-n.*l).*x)
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like your circular shift is only 2 samples but your phase slope (W) is for 3 samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Your two methods shift in opposite directions
2. You do an extra FFT on `y` which is already a frequency domain quantity

Here is the modified code that works

```
%% shift property
x=[1:8];
N=length(x);
n=0:N-1;
k=0:N-1;
X=fft(x);
l=3;%shift amount
% MOD1: shift in the other direction
y=circshift(X,-l,2);%here 2 means shift along 2nd dimension which are columns
W=exp(j*2*pi/N);
RHS=fft(y);
LHS=fft(W.^(-n.*l).*x);

% MOD2: print the error agains y. RHS is nonsense
d = LHS-y;
fprintf('Error = %6.2fdB\n',10*log10((d*d')/(y*y')));
```